# Trying to read unique words into a file, but somthing wrong with memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memory-management

got a weird problem in following code, for some reason buff is overrides the arr at every iteration of the while loop.
code is meant to read from a text file line by line, read tow word per line and search each on in the 'arr' array. if found will return its index, if not it will store it in next availble place and return the index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*given a new word t, it searches in arr for it, if found returns the index
if not found returns first availble index and stores it */
int searchIndex(char * t,char **arr, int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        if(arr[i]==NULL){
            arr[i]=t;
            return i;
        }
        if(strcmp(arr[i],t)==0)
        return i;

    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


   char *token =(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)) ;
   const char s[2] = " ";
   FILE *fp;
   char buff[255];
   int index;

   int V=3;  // Number of vertices in graph
   char ** arr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*V) ;
   fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

//loop reads words from file and assigns each word a uniqe index in arr
   while(fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp))

   {
      printf("arr in begining of iteration: \n");
      printf("%s \t",arr[0]);
      printf("%s \t",arr[1]);
      printf("%s \t",arr[2]);
      printf("\n");


    token = strtok(buff, s);
    printf("first token read: %s \t",token);
    index = searchIndex(token,arr,V);
    printf("first tokens index: %d \t",index);
    printf("\n");


     token = strtok(NULL, s);
     printf("second token read: %s \t",token);
     index = searchIndex(token,arr,V);
     printf("second tokens index: %d \t",index);
     printf("\n");
     printf("arr at end of iteration: \n");
     printf("%s \t",arr[0]);
     printf("%s \t",arr[1]);
     printf("%s \n",arr[2]);
     printf("\n"); 
  }
   fclose(fp);



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)`loops over `n+1` elements. Is this what you intend? We can only guess, as you hide `allocArray()`!

Comment: Also, you might like to indent your code more nicely before presenting it to the world.

Comment: `char *token =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)) ;` this line is wrong for at least three separate reasons, can you identify them?

Comment: it should be: char * token =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char *)) ; ?

Comment: `arr[i]=t;` --> `arr[i]=strdup(t);`

Comment: _it should be: char token =(char)malloc(sizeof(char *));_ just only `char *token;`

Comment: `char **arr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*V);` --> `char **arr = (char **)calloc(V, sizeof(char*));` Because your cord needs initialized area.

Comment: thanks BLUEPIXY! any idea why    if(strcmp(arr[i],t)==0)  isnt finding existing string? dbg shows that t has an extra \n?

Comment: `fgets` will need to be removed in advance because it contains a newline. E.g. `const char s[2] = " ";` --> `const char s[] = " \t\n";` or `token` and `while(fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp))` replace with `while(1==fscanf(fp, "%254s", buff)){`

Comment: OK so the reasons are: 1. Thou shall not cast the return value of malloc (search SO to find out why). 2. Allocating a single character on the heap is pointless most of the time. 3. You are not using the allocated storage and in fact leaking it.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
char ** arr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*V) ;
```

you allocate `V` pointers.

Here you pass what had been allocated along with how many elements `arr` points to

```
index = searchIndex(token,arr,V);
```

And inside `searchIndex()` you iterate over one **more** element as you allocated:

```
int searchIndex(char * t,char **arr, int n){
  int i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
```

To fix this iterater one less:

```
int searchIndex(char * t, char ** arr, int n) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration you read into `buff` from the file, tokenise `buff` splitting on space, and then store pointers to the tokenised strings in `arr`. Note: because you are storing pointers to locations within `buff` the next read into `buf` may overwrite data in `arr`.

In `searchIndex()` you need to store *copies* of the tokens in `arr`. You can use `strdup()` for this. Also you are iterating 1 time too many in the search loop which is another problem, but not one that directly causes overwriting of `arr`. One other thing, once `arr` is full the function does not return an explicit value (it could be anything!) - you could return -1 to indicate a full array:

```
int searchIndex(char * t,char **arr, int n) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            arr[i] = strdup(t);
            return i;
        }
        if (strcmp(arr[i], t) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks to all, still have one problem, no matter what i do arr size stays only 2, if i try accessing index beyond 1 i get error, any ideas?

Comment: `arr` size is actually 3 as per the variable `V`. Max index is 2. Increase `V` to increase the size of `arr`.

Comment: You'll need to explain "isn't working". Is it a compilation error or a runtime error? What output do you see?

Comment: Note that malloc doesn't initialise the allocated memory, i.e. `char ** arr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*V);` may not result in V char * pointers all initialised to NULL. Either initialize these after calling malloc, or use calloc like this: `arr = (char **)calloc(V, sizeof(char *));`

Comment: Thanks to all of you! i dont use c a lot and you helped me very much!

Comment: @YakovAbrams:  If this answers your question, please vote it up and accept it.